# How to toggle a map locations using Map-buttons in JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a new svg map and want to (revial) the place details of every location by mouse over and (hide) it by mouseout. but when a location clicked, want to stay revialed the current locatition.

I can do this by writing lots of codes, but would like to know if there is a better way to write less code with JS (not JQuery).
I did this (but I have lots of location's buttons and locations.

```
var firstlocBut = document.getElementById("firstlocBut");
 var firstlocation = document.getElementById("firstlocation");
 var SecLocBut = document.getElementById("secLocBut");
 var SecLocation = document.getElementById("secLocation");

 function mousover(e){

        if(e.getAttribute("id") == ("firstlocBut")) {
firstLocation.classList.add ("revialLocationclass")
        } else if(e.getAttribute("id") == ("SecLocBut")){
        SecLocation.classList.add ("revialLocationclass")
         }};

function mousleave(e){
        if(e.getAttribute("id") == ("firstlocBut")) {
firstlocBut.classList.remove ("revialLocationclass")
        }else if(e.getAttribute("id") == ("SecLocBut")){
SecLocation.classList.remove ("revialLocationclass")
        }};

function onclick(){
if(e.getAttribute("id") == ("firstlocBut")) {
firstBut.classList.add("revialLocationclassforever")
}else if(e.getAttribute("id") == ("secLocBut")) {
SecLocBut.classList.add("revialLocationclassforever")
}};
```

I want to do this:

onmouseover (on a location's button) = {hide all locations and revial just the currents' location.

onmouseout (from a location's button)={hide all locations (exept clicked).

onclick (on a location button) ={if it's location is already revialed, hide it, otherwise revial it (and vise versa ) (forever) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## New Answer (Based on added information)

**Disclaimer**: None of the code is not tested!

After looking at your website this is what i would do:

Get all **top level** `g` elements and give them a content id, so for example: (Of course if you have ids for all your elements, use those and I'm sure your able to create an array somehow to loop through it. If not, write me but please try it first)

```html
<g contentId="1">[...]</g>
```

(of course you can call it what you like)

In JavaScript you can then create an array with all the texts or whatever you want to display and loop through all elements that have a content id like so:

```
let contentTable = [
    {title: "Foo", detail: "Bar"},
    {title: "Hello", detail: "World"}
]

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('g [contentId]')).forEach(element => {
    let contentId = element.getAttribute('contentId');

    // Here add your mouse listeners like
    element.addEventListener('[...]', () => [...]);

});
```

Alternatively if you want more readable code you could use an object instead of an element so the html would be:

```
<g contentId="hauptbahnhof">[...]</g>
```

And the JavaScript code:

```
let contentTable = {
    hauptbahnhof: {[...]},
    [...]
}
```

Did I still miss something important? Hit me up in the comments!

## Old Answer

Here is a really primitive example how I would do it. I didn't write any fancy display code but just the bare minimum and logged into the console when the mouse enters and leaves.

```js
// Constants

// List of "locations"
const locations = [
  {"color": "blue", "location": "New York"},
  {"color": "green", "location": "Foo"},
  {"color": "yellow", "location": "bar"},
  {"color": "red", "location": "Rio"}
]

// DOM Elements... also constants :D
const container = document.getElementById('container');

// Create "location markers"
locations.forEach(location => {
  // Create location element
  let e = document.createElement('div');
  // Some primitive styling
  e.style.backgroundColor = location.color;
  e.style.height = "10px";
  
  // Add hover event listener
  e.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    // Here some fancy display stuff
    // I'm just logging it
    console.log(`Hover enter; Location: ${location.location}`)
  });
  e.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    // Here some fancy removal of added display stuff
    // Again, just logging that the mouse left
    console.log(`Hover leave; Location: ${location.location}`)
  })
  
  // Append the child to a container
  container.appendChild(e);
});
```

```html
<div id="container" style="border: 1px solid black">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. 
This is helpful for another cases I believe, but I couldn't make my problem clear I believe.

Comment: You just need to define your locations in an array, you could even fetch them from a server. The important point is that you dynamically create them. Is your problem just that you already have your stuff in HTML and don't want to write tons of functions? I still would recommend doing what I wrote but otherwise, I would write code to get all the elements and loop through them and so apply the `onClick` the same way

Comment: wow... tnx budy. 
I think it's helpful if you take a look to the page:
http://fetetest.hereyshop.com/karte/
Passowrd: muze

(now you would see how it works with hover. and I want to whenever I click, the location stays on even if I move the mouse.) and yes, I had to write lots of codes :)